# How does function overloading work in the following case?

Tags: c++

The following code compiles and runs but I'm not sure what exactly is going on at a lower level. Doesn't a reference just store the address of the object being referenced? If so, both test functions are receiving an address as a parameter? Or is the C++ implementation able to differentiate between these types in some other way?

```
int main() {
    int i = 1;
    cout << test(i) << endl;
}

char test(int &i) {
    return 'a';
}

char test(int *i) {
    return 'b';
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `int&` and `int*` are distinct types and `i` can be treated as a `int&` but not as a `int*`, overload resolution is absolutely unambiguous here.

It doesn't matter at this point that references are just a somewhat cloaked kind of pointer. From a language point of view they are distinct types.

Answer (score 2):

References in C++ are more akin to an alias than a pointer. A reference is not a seperate variable in itself, but it is a new "name" for an exisiting variable. In your example the first test would get called because you are passing an integer to the function. A pointer is a seperate variable that holds the address of another variable so for the second function to be called you would have to call test with a pointer. Like so.. `test(&i);` While a tad confusing the operator & gets the address of a variable while a variable declared with an & like `int &i` declares a reference.

Answer (score 1):

you code only matches with `char test(int&i)` since you are passing an `int&` to the function and that can not be converted to `int*`